Azure Devops | Get user/group access into project and resources(pipelines, repos, etc.) by API call
I'm trying to fetch Azure Devops user and group access into project and project resources(pipelines, repos, etc.).
I tried to find an API from the documentation that assisted.
ChatGPT offered to use:
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces/{namespace_id}/permissions?&descriptors={user_descriptor}&api-version=6.0 but it seems that descriptors doesn't exist (got 404 when adding it) .
The API should reflect what we can see in the UI:

I will glad for your help.
Thanks

Do you really need to use the REST API or can you use, as an alternative, the Azure DevOps CLI?

Need a REST API for my application

Hi @omer blechman, have you checked my answer below to use REST API Access Control Lists - Query? Did it work for you?

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, I checked your answer but unfortunately, it didn't help for my case because of the amount of the APIs that I need to make in order to fetch project permissions. (I need to go over all the users/groups and the namespaces)

@omer blechman, I'm afraid there is no other API except REST API Access Control Lists - Query can get all permissions. For these resource types, projectGit, ref, release,repo and tfvc, you can use the REST API Permissions Report - Create to get the permissions report. But it only supports these types. See my update below.

I don't find such a REST API https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces/{namespace_id}/permissions?&descriptors={user_descriptor}&api-version=6.0 in the official docs. The closest API I can find is Security Namespaces - Query, which is used to list all security namespaces or just the specified namespace but it doesn't have permissions and descriptors.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces/{securityNamespaceId}?localOnly={localOnly}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
To check the permissions of users or groups in the project/resources, you can use REST API Access Control Lists - Query.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?token={token}&descriptors={descriptors}&includeExtendedInfo={includeExtendedInfo}&recurse={recurse}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
According to Security namespace and permission reference for Azure DevOps,

Security namespaces are used to store access control lists (ACLs) on tokens. Each family of resources, such as work items or Git repositories, is secured through a unique namespace. Each security namespace contains zero or more ACLs. Each ACL contains a token, an inherit flag, and a set of zero or more access control entries (ACEs). Each ACE contains an identity descriptor, an allowed permissions bitmask, and a denied permissions bitmask. Tokens are arbitrary strings representing resources in Azure DevOps.

The Allow, Deny and AceExtendedInformation are bitmask, you need to decode it to find the corresponding permissions. To better understand how to use this API to check the permission, you can check this useful blog Azure DevOps Security API demystified.

Update
For these resource types, projectGit, ref, release,repo and tfvc, you can use the REST API Permissions Report - Create to get the permissions report. The following is part of my project-level All Repositories permission report. You can see the user/group and corresponding permissions.
[
    {
        "Descriptor": "aad.***",
        "Id": "233***",
        "AccountName": "t***@***.com",
        "DisplayName": "t***",
        "Resource": {
            "ResourceType": "projectGit",
            "ResourceId": "f003e7d1***",
            "ResourceName": null
        },
        "Permissions": [
            {
                "PermissionName": "Advanced Security: manage and dismiss alerts",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Advanced Security: manage settings",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Advanced Security: view alerts",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Bypass policies when completing pull requests",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Bypass policies when pushing",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Contribute",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Contribute to pull requests",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Create branch",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Create repository",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Create tag",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Delete or disable repository",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Edit policies",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Manage notes",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Manage permissions",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Read",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Remove others' locks",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            },
            {
                "PermissionName": "Rename repository",
                "EffectivePermission": "NotSet"
            }
        ],
        "Error": null
    },
    {
        "Descriptor": "aad.***",
    ...
    }
}
]

